# How to make textEdit transparent? and should allow to write text the text should be visible?

Tags: wpf, devexpress-wpf

I have a requirement in icici bank i have a cheque in that i have 2 print user name,amount in figures but the textEdit should be invisible and allow to write and read.

```
    <Window xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"  x:Class="WpfApplication11.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid Margin="0,10,0,0">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="c:\users\it-prog3\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WpfApplication11\WpfApplication11\Images\ICICI.jpg"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <dxe:TextEdit Margin="31,60,68,221"  />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, you cannot do that using a devexpress textedit. I am also using devexpress and had a similar requirement like this. What I did was use a textbox. Try considering using a textbox?

In XAML you can directly set the Background property to Transparent:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Background="Transparent" />
```

In code-behind you can set the background to transparent using the following code:

```
TextBox TextBox1 = new TextBox 
{
    Width = 75,
    Height = 25,
    Background = Brushes.Transparent
};
```